# Cron job issues in the Cpanel & not further update a database column

Tags: php

```
<?php
include_once('dbcon.php');
$qry = "SELECT * FROM `uncn`";
$btr = mysqli_query($conec,$qry);
while(mysqli_num_rows($btr)){
    $try = "UPDATE `uncn` SET `comp`='1'";
    $vti = mysqli_query($conec,$try);
    
}
?>
<!---Done---->
```

I have write a cron job to update a column in database (twice a day). But all day, I have not added a data in this column when we manually added a data in database only this (comp) column, the new data not to be stored, due to the cron job.

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home2/onlineti/public_html/hibal4e4ecl/res.php
```

I am tried to update with new data in this column (comp)

Comment: Without the code for `res.php`, it's hard to tell what it's doing. Since it works on the command line, I'm going to guess it's unable to load an included/required file because it's not using the full path.

Comment: Please do not add your code to comments, it makes it extremely hard to read and troubleshoot. Instead, [edit] your post and add the code there.

Comment: `include_once('dbcon.php');` Include looks for the file where the program is being run, not where the parent code resides. Cron will usually run the code from `/`, so you'll need the full path so that your code can always find `dbcon.php`

Comment: include_once('dbcon.php'); include full path and try it